# how to evaluate $\int \ln (\sqrt{e^x+\sin x}) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I'm newbie here, how to evaluate $$\int \ln (\sqrt{e^x+\sin x}) dx$$ I tried to use integration by parts but it didn't work.

Comment: Could you please cite the full task description? What means "evaluate", there should be an integration interval. Is there something said about "numerically"? Use that the integrand is equal for instance to $x/2+\ln(1+e^{-x}\sin x)/2$.

Comment: HINT:

$$\int\ln\sqrt{e^x+\sin(x)}\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\int\left(\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(e^x+\sin(x)\right)\right)\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\int\ln\left(e^x+\sin(x)\right)\space\text{d}x$$

Comment: Probably because there is no elementary antiderivative.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio i even think one needs hypergeometrics here...

Comment: yes, that question have their integration interval. It's from 1 to 6. But in order to solve this question, we must first knowing the antiderivative of the function.

Answer (score 2):

*This is not an answer but it is too long for a comment.*

As already said in answers and comments, I do not think that there is any hope to get a closed form expression for the antiderivative.

However, assuming that you need to compute the value of the integral over a small range, you could expand the integrand as a Taylor series. This is not the easiest one to work, but, by the end, we could get $$\log \left(\sqrt{e^x+\sin (x)}\right)=x-\frac{3 x^2}{4}+\frac{5 x^3}{6}-\frac{25 x^4}{24}+\frac{17 x^5}{12}-\frac{361
   x^6}{180}+\frac{184 x^7}{63}-\frac{1459 x^8}{336}+\frac{59497
   x^9}{9072}-\frac{758203 x^{10}}{75600}+O\left(x^{11}\right)$$ So $$\int_0^a\log \left(\sqrt{e^x+\sin (x)}\right)\,dx=\frac{a^2}{2}-\frac{a^3}{4}+\frac{5 a^4}{24}-\frac{5 a^5}{24}+\frac{17
   a^6}{72}-\frac{361 a^7}{1260}+\frac{23 a^8}{63}-\frac{1459 a^9}{3024}+\frac{59497
   a^{10}}{90720}-\frac{758203 a^{11}}{831600}+O\left(a^{12}\right)$$

Let us try for $a=\frac{1}{10}$. The above formula gives $$\frac{594880155859783}{124740000000000000}\approx 0.00476896068510328$$ while an accurate numerical integration would lead to $$0.00476896068623222$$ The results become worse and worse (not to say more) when $a$ increases. For example, if $a=\frac 12$, the above formula gives $$\frac{261574073}{2554675200}\approx 0.102390344181523$$ while numerical integration would lead to $$0.102574149117685$$

For sure, you could add more terms to the expansion but this will not change the problem.

**Edit**

Looking at the plot of $\log \left(\sqrt{e^x+\sin (x)}\right)$ it differs from the plot of $\frac x 2$ mainly for $0<x<2\pi$. So, for any value of $a >2\pi$, we could approximate the value of the integral by $$I=\int_0^a\log \left(\sqrt{e^x+\sin (x)}\right)\,dx=\int_0^{2\pi} \Big(\log \left(\sqrt{e^x+\sin (x)}\right)-\frac x 2\Big)\,dx+\frac {a^2}4$$ that is to say, more or less,$$I\approx\frac {a^2}4+0.222885$$

Answer (score 1):

There is no closed form for this integral so any technique you use won't work.

Edit: As you have now supplied a range you could evaluate the definite integral via numerial techniques such as the [trapezoid rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) or similar. However determining the indefinite integral is not the way to evaluate this problem.

High precision application of the trapezoid rules gives a definite integral (from 0 to 6) of: $8.86445077465226...$

Comment: My Math teacher told me to never give and so I guess I will stick to it and try!

Comment: I'm not saying you can't do it. I'm saying no one can do it. It is impossible to express the answer using any combination of $\sin$, $\cos$, $\tan$, $\ln$, exponentials, roots, fractions, arithmetic, etc.

Comment: Your answer is real good. To illustrate the difficulty, for the same range (not using  the trapezoid rule), I got a value of $9.22293$ !! In fact, if the upper bound $a$ becomes large, we should approach $\frac {a^2}4$. Cheers :-)

Comment: i did use very very tiny trapezoids. Certainly this degree isn't achievable by hand.